# Клиент - серверное приложение C#

Tags: c#, .net, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер

Пишу академическое приложение. Подскажи пожалуйста, допустим у меня есть сервер и есть куча клиентов. Мне надо периодически менять настройки на всех клиентах. Что бы не бегать к каждому. Я вижу это как интегрированный сервис в серверное приложение, с него происходит какое то событие (например отправляю строку update), на клиенте слушаю порт? Но тут надо наверное по таймеру надо дергать метод из сервиса. 
Если пришла команда Update, методом дернуть настройки один раз
Или делать на соккетах? Отправил в порт когда необходимо массив байт с настройками, на клиенте просто принял, что пришло.
Что-то я в замешательстве как правильно поступить. Гуи пока сделал в таком виде сугубо для теста.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: На клиенте слушать порт нельзя. Он может быть за пятью NAT'ами.

Comment: Что в таком случае делать? Прикрутить к клиенту WCF сервис? Который крутится на стороне сервера.

Comment: Я вам ещё одну очевидную вещь скажу: не на всех клиентах Windows, особенно в академических проектах.

Comment: раз приложение академическое, то я бы просто читал настройки с сервера раз в час (ну или раз в 5-10 минут) и все дела.

Comment: @JDo клиенты могут сами раз в Х секунд/минут опрашивать сервер на предмет изменений. Заодно эти запросы можно считать за "пинг" и по ним понимать, какие из клиентов ещё "живы"

Comment: @tym32167, у меня дефалтные настройки на клиенте уже есть. Мне надо например их изменить, я на сервере кликнул кнопку и зааплоадил новые настройки. Менять только вручную. И настройки нужны на самом клиенте(например в конфиг или файле настроек).

Comment: ну так кешируйте из на клиенте как хотите, хоть в конфиг, хоть куда. Просто с какой то периодичностью опрашивайте сервер, если приходят новые настройки - обновляем кеш

Comment: Некоторые проекты (например Battle.net) используют JSON-RPC. То есть они поднимают у пользователя сервер, который принимает простые команды. Тут только одно но: Я лично без понятия как реализовать грамотную работу у всех клиентов, ведь у кого то может порт заблокирован, к кому то вовсе нет доступа. Но для небольшой демонстрации я думаю без проблем можно использовать JSON-RPC.

Comment: Рассылка сообщений от сервера клиентам, конечно, возможна, но если какой-то клиент подключится позже, то он этого сообщения не получит. Конечно, при каждом подключении клиент тоже должен сперва получать информацию о новых настройках, если они есть. А вообще, клиент должен передавать в запросе свою текущую версию: если она равна текущей версии сервера, тот возвращает респонз с данными. Если версия клиента устарела, сервер вернет ошибку с причиной: нужно обновить настройки - тогда клиент должен запросить это обновление.

Comment: Я бы на вашем месте посмотрел в сторону SignalR.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov спасибо! Хорошее предложение!